# Creating Map where values are methods which return an observable throwing TS error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I wonder why does my code throw an error. I have a given type for method

```
type ReturnObsFunc = (str?: string) => Observable<any>;
```

And I want to create map using Map Object. But unfortunately it doesn't work

```
  private getFilterSource$(filterType: FilterType): Observable<any> {
    const sourceMap = new Map<FilterType, AnotherFunc>([
      [FilterType.SubClient, this._filtersService.getClients$],
      [FilterType.Product, this._filtersService.getProducts$],
    ]);

    return sourceMap.get(filterType);

    //Type 'ReturnObsFunc ' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.
  }
```

There a solution with object map, but I'd like to know is it possible with Map.

```
  private getFilterSource$(filterType: FilterType): Observable<any> {
    const sourceMap = {
      [FilterType.SubClient]: this._filtersService.getClients$,
      [FilterType.Product]: this._filtersService.getProducts$,
    };

    return sourceMap[filterType]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, I've got the answer - getFilterSource$ should return ReturnObsFunc not Observable. It's obvious.